# How to restore an image split in several CDs?

Tags: clonezilla

I am helping to recycle and restore some old computers at a local charity. At home, I have created a Xubuntu installation in a virtual machine, so every needed program was installed and everything was configured and updated properly. Then, I used Clonezilla to make an image, and added it to a [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) live DVD so it can be autoinstallable.

It works great! The problem is that many of the computers don't have a DVD drive, they have only a CD drive available, and the image is ~2 GB in size.

I know that Clonezilla allows to split the images, but I haven't found any information about the restore process of split images: do they have all in the same place before starting the restore, or is there any way that I can configure it to ask me for the next CDs?

Also, I know that USB would be a good solution, but it's USB 1.1, it's not available in all the computers, and I don't have enough USB drives to install 7-8 computers at a time.

Comment: You might check out this software...http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp

Comment: That looks nice. But what does it do better than Clonezilla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recovery Clonezilla live with multiple CDs or DVDs is not implemented yet. Now all the files have to be in one CD or DVD if you choose to create the recovery iso file.

Source: http://clonezilla.org/

I personally use Acronis which is not Freeware so won;t bother recommending it here as I'm presuming Freeware is what you're after. (It's very good though)

Perhaps this thread will help: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/disk-imaging-clonezilla-or-partimage-694104/

Comment: Ah, you're right. It was a bit hidden. Yes, I am looking for something free, since this is for a charity. I tried also restoring via network, but we are using a 10Mbps switch and the 10-15 minutes that it takes to restore with the DVD become a minimum of 5-6 hours. Anyway, I'll try to install temporarily the available DVD drives, or plug several hard disks to a computer and restore the image to all of them. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: @Martin M You could put the image onto a spare HDD and open the case on the computers you're restoring and restore from the Secomdary HDD. The restore will be very quick, it should make up for the time you lose opening up the cases.